# Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7

How can I change the colour and/or the background image of the lock/login screen? I'd like to set it to something nicer than the default blue with flowers.

Answer (score 0):

This method will require you to modify the registry

1. Open the Windows Start menu and enter regedit into the search bar.
2. Right click on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and select Find.
3. Search for OEMBackground, which should be in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Background`. If the key does not exist, add a new **DWORD value** with the name **OEMBackground**.
4. Double click on the entry **OEMBackground**, and change the value from **0** to **1**.
5. Open Windows Explorer and go to the following path: `%windir%\system32\oobe`.
6. Create a new folder named **info**, and open it.
7. Create a new folder within **info** named **backgrounds**.
8. Rename your desired wallpaper as **backgroundDefault.jpg** and place it inside the folder **backgrounds** (images must be less than 245KB in size).

That should do the trick, now just lock your PC, log off or reboot and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools also to change the logon screen

http://tweaks.com/software/tweakslogon/download/tweakslogon.zip
Use the above link to download tweakslogon

The application will help you to change the background image of logon screen
[image]